# PageReference constructor removing parameters

Tags: apex, visualforce

the url that I'm putting into the pagereference constructor isn't the one that's popping out. it's stripping off the last &retURL that's part of my &save_new_URL.

what's going on and how do i fix it?

**code:**

```
String url = '/setup/ui/recordtypeselect.jsp?ent=Task';
url+= '&retURL=/' + this.who_Id; 
url+='&save_new_URL=/apex/taskOverRide?who_id=' + this.who_Id + '&retURL=/' +this.who_id ;
system.debug('URL: ' + url);
PageReference p = new Pagereference(url);
system.debug('URL: ' + p.getUrl());
p.setRedirect(true);
return p;
```

**string URL output:**

```
URL: /setup/ui/recordtypeselect.jsp?ent=Task&retURL=/003e0000004owon&save_new_URL=/apex/taskOverRide?who_id=003e0000004owon&retURL=/003e0000004owon
```

**output from the constructor**

```
 /setup/ui/recordtypeselect.jsp?ent=Task&retURL=%2F003e0000004owon&save_new_URL=%2Fapex%taskOverRide%3Fwho_id%3D003e0000004owon
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the parameter retUrl twice, and I think pageReference notices that and only uses one of the retUrls.

When you add the parameters to the URL, certain characters are encoded.  Check out this resource:   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding

Try encoding the second retUrl yourself, and then it shouldn't be confused and parsed out.

```
string saveUrl='&save_new_URL=/apex/taskOverRide?who_id=' + this.who_Id + '&retURL=/' +this.who_id ;
//encode the URL
saveUrl=saveUrl.replace('&','%26').repalce('=','%3D').replace('/','%2F'); //.replace(otherNecessaryCharacters,accordingly)

url+=saveUrl;
```

Comment: Why not just use EncodingUtil.urlEncode and EncodingUtil.urlDecode?

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_restful_encodingUtil.htm

Comment: saveUrl = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(saveUrl,'UTF-8');
url += saveUrl

Comment: Yup, that'll do it all too in one step.  And it's nice to know what's actually being encoded.  That's a useful class for converting to Base64 and back!